# Truffle error during migration

Tags: contract-development, web3js, truffle, microsoft-azure

I am getting an error when I run :

```
truffle migrate --network production
```

Error

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
Deploying Migrations...
... 0xc10be773bf8c2cbb38c789765bf063413d1de8285cab63b078f3ec48263f3579
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: Contract transaction couldn't be found after 50 blocks
```

I adjusted the gas value and checked whether syncing is running but `eth.syncing` returns false. It means its not syncing related issue.

truffle.js:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 7545,
      network_id: '*' // Match any network id
    },
    production:{
      host: '.....cloudapp.azure.com',
      port: 8545,
      network_id: '*', // Match any network id
      gas: 5000000,

    }
  },

}
```

Comment: See https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/660#issuecomment-343066784

Comment: Check `gasPrice` it might be too low, also adjust gas to be just enough. A large value of gas might delay your tx, some miners favour tx with small gas because they can fit more in a block.

Comment: @niksmac I tried all things mentioned on github issue but none of the proposed solutions fixed the error.